# What is the means of terms "Building Block" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

for example title of this article is "The JavaScript Building Blocks: Data Types, Literals, and Variables"

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169501

What is the means of terms "Building Blocks" in JavaScript? Is it related to box on web-page, CSS box model?

Answer (score 4):

The term "Building Blocks" is just a metaphor for the basic, essential elements needed to create something. It has no meaning specific to javascript.

The article is using it as a means of saying that it is dealing with the most elemental parts of javascript that you'll need to know.

Answer (score 1):

No, it means the basic parts of the language.

It is an English term that means the basic parts of a larger whole (comes from building - where they are made from bricks/blocks).

See the [Chambers dictionary](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?query=Building+Blocks&title=21st&sourceid=Mozilla-search), in particular 3 (highlighted):

> building block noun 1 a hollow or solid block, larger than a brick, made of concrete or other material. 2 a child's toy, usually a cube made of wood. **3 any of the separate parts out of which something is built.**

Comment: "basic parts of a larger whole" ok. "Building Blocks" means basic of language.

Comment: In general I understand Block mean a "box"

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - In this instance, it is an _informal_ way of talking about the small parts, not any "box" or "brick".

Comment: @Oded -  Thanks for your answer. So "The JavaScript Building Blocks: Data Types, Literals, and Variables" and "The JavaScript Basics: Data Types, Literals, and Variables" both title has same sense? , am i right?

Comment: @oded: It's not only used in English. It's used even in Swedish. I have no idea where it come from first.

Comment: @Oded - title of this article http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/compose-functions-as-building-blocks/ is "Compose: functions as building blocks" here the terms "building blocks" also has same sense? I found terms "Building blocks" on many articles. and I think they are not for basics of javascript. I can be wrong though.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - yes. Building larger systems from functions.

Comment: @some - The term is used in many languages. The one used in the question was English.

Comment: @Oded: That was my point, that the term is used in many languages. I'm sorry for not making that clear in my first comment.

Comment: @Oded - On this page http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_examples.asp there is a section of example of JavaScripts called "JavaScript Statements, Comments and Blocks". And there a example link of "JavaScript blocks" which goes to this page http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_blocks . I asked to my one of my friend who is programmer and he is saying, Block means group of code lines which we put inside {......}. I want to know your thoughts on this.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - I think his understanding is fine. The word has many meanings, depending on context, like other words.

Comment: @Oded - What you found like "Rep farming" in my this question?

Answer (score 0):

It's a colloquial/informal way of saying the most basic elements of the language that are needed for most tasks that you might want to do.